# Let $f$ be continuous and positive

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

Let $f$ be continuous and positive, and assume $\int_0^\infty f(x)\mathrm dx$ converges.
I'm supposed to prove the below integral converges:

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{f(x)}{\int_0^\infty f(t)\mathrm dt} \mathrm dx $$
I attempted $u$-substitution with $u=\int_0^\infty f(x)\mathrm dx$, but that didn't take me anywhere.

Comment: For convergence, you need something to vary. What is varying here?

Comment: *Hint:* the denominator is a constant and you know it is finite, so you only have to show that $\int_0^1 f(x) dx$ converges.

Comment: The substitution $u=\int_0^{\infty} f(x)dx$ does not make sense. RHS is not variable , it is a constant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just $\int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx$ divided by the constant $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$. Since everything is positive, and therefore $\int_{1+\varepsilon}^Mf(x)\,dx$ is "increasing" and bounded by $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$, we have convergence.

Answer (score 5):

This is trivial:
$$\int_0^ \infty f(t)dt$$ converges by assumption and thus can be pulled outside the integral. Then, it suffices to note that
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{f(x)}{\int_0^ \infty f(t)dt}dx= \frac{1}{\int_0^\infty f(t)dt} \int_1^\infty f(x) dx $$
$$\leq \frac{1}{\int_0^\infty f(t)dt} \int_0^\infty f(x) dx < \infty$$

where we used that $f$ is positive in the step to justify the inequality.